# How to get power life of cell phone using Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

I tried using nativescript like this but it doesnt work:

```
battery = navigator.battery || navigator.webkitBattery || navigator.mozBattery || navigator.msBattery;

console.log("battery level: ", Math.floor(this.battery.level * 100) + "%");
```

Comment: you have to get it using native codes for respective platform.

Comment: i want it for android can u help me how??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to write respective native codes for getting Battery info.

for android you can register broadcastreciever for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`. and for ios you can use `UIDevice.currentDevice.batteryLevel`

example:

```
import { android as androidApp, ios as iosApp } from "application";
import { ios as iosUtils } from "utils/utils";

if (iosApp){
  iosUtils.getter(UIDevice, UIDevice.currentDevice).batteryMonitoringEnabled = true;
  let battery = +(iosUtils.getter(UIDevice, UIDevice.currentDevice).batteryLevel * 100);
}else{
  androidApp.registerBroadcastReceiver(android.content.Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED,(context: android.content.Context, intent: android.content.Intent) =>{
        let level = intent.getIntExtra(android.os.BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        let scale = intent.getIntExtra(android.os.BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        let percent = (level / scale) * 100.0;
    });
}
```